# ACM 10038 Jolly Jumpers

Tags: c

I have written the solution code of [Jolly Jump problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=979) (ACM 10038 uva).
My Code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int count=0;
  int Number[3000]={0};
  int Absolute[3000]={0};
  bool flag=true;
  while(scanf("%d",&count)){
   for(int i=0;i<count;++i){
     scanf("%d",&Number[i]);
     Absolute[i]=0;
   }
   for(int j=0;j<count-1;++j){
     int diff=Number[j]-Number[j+1];
     if(diff<0)diff*=-1;
     Absolute[diff]=1;
   }
   flag=true;
   for(int x=1;x<count;++x){
     if(Absolute[x]!=1){
       flag=false;
       break;
     }
   }
   if(flag)printf("Jolly\n");
   else printf("Not Jolly\n");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

But the conmmited result is Time limit exceeded. Why? How do I revise my code to lower the run time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is probably exceeding the time limit because it never finishes. If/when `scanf()` returns `EOF`, the following will never stop looping:

```
while(scanf("%d",&count)){
    // whatever...
}
```

In these online programming problems, it's usually a good idea to at least run your proposed solution against the example data they provide in the question and see if you get the expected output.  If your program doesn't produce the expected output, then you know you have a problem to fix (and you have something concrete to debug).

Answer (score 1):

Infinite loop! Just replace `while(scanf("%d",&count))` with `while(scanf("%d",&count) != EOF)` and you're done.

From `man scanf`:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> ```
>    These  functions  return  the  number  of  input items successfully
>    matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even
>    zero in the event of an early matching failure.
>
>    The  value  EOF  is  returned if the end of input is reached before
>    either the  first  successful  conversion  or  a  matching  failure
>    occurs.  EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case
>    the error indicator for the stream  (see  ferror(3))  is  set,  and
>    errno is set indicate the error.
> ```

I'm also a competitor. One hint I can give you is to always create a input file (in.txt) and an output file (out.txt), redirect the input to the program and compare the outputs using `diff`:

```
$ cat in.txt
4 1 4 2 3
5 1 4 2 -1 6

$ cat out.txt
Jolly
Not jolly

$ ./jolly_jumpers < in.txt > my_out.txt

$ diff -s out.txt my_out.txt
Files out.txt and my_out.txt are identical
```

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered that before.

What I did was adding the difference of every two respective elements to a vector and at the end sorting it.

Now what you need to do is just to check if every element of this vector is exactly 1 more than the previous element. Also, checking the first element of this sorted vector to be 1 and the last, to be n-1.